# Problems with "Access Modifiers" in a class

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers

I can't use any types of "Access Modifiers" in may "Class". If i try to use for example "Public" or "Internal" it comes with fail-code's "CS1519" "CS0106"

[image: image of code problem]

I tried to make a "Method" in my "Class" but I couldn't make it visible to my "Program.cs" because my "Class" gave the failcoat and came to look like in the picture.

I hoppe someone can help me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

At this level you aren't able to apply any access modifier. This level is the level of local methods which are accessible from the method contains them. Thus, any access modifier has no sense.

If you need to add another method to the 'bil' class, you should put it after line 20.

```
public class bil
{
    public bil()
    {
        ... // constructor code here
    } // line 20
    public void PrintInfo()
    {
         Console.WriteLine(" Car");
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant link for the asker: [MS Learn - Local functions - C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

Comment: I have tried to do as you say, and now it does not making a feel in the class but when I go in to program.cs, it still making a fail 

CS1061: 'bog' does not contain a definition for 'PrintInfo' and noaaccessible extension method 'Printinfo' accepting a first argument oftype 'bog' coulce found (are you missing a using directive or anassembly reference?)

It seems like it can't find "PrintInfo"

Comment: Pls provide the full code in your question.

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5fwb.png) 
I don't know if this is what you meant

Comment: Pls. edit your question to add your code, especially from 'bil.cs'.